# Advice needed for ReactJS Equivalent of React-Native-Web stylesheet.flatten

Tags: reactjs, react-native-web, react-native-stylesheet

So we are trying to remove React-Native-Web from our codebase, and I was wondering what the ReactJS equivalent of `stylesheet.flatten` was?

We are using it like this;

```
const flattenMyStylesheets = StyleSheet.flatten(styles);
const style = Object.keys(flattenMyStylesheets || {}).length ? { style: flattenMyStylesheets } : {};

  return {
    ...
    props: {
      ...style
    }
  };
```

Failing that what would be the best way to swap this out

Comment: So as it turns out, we were already passing the flattened data as an object, so just resorted to this instead `const style = props.style; return { ... props: { ...style } };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually go the StyleSheet way with native React.

I'd recommend using either a [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/) approach, or with React you can use pure objects for styling instead of relying on the `StyleSheet` RN API. See [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/styling-in-react-4-ways-style-react-app/)

Note: I'm a React Native + React dev

Comment: Ah I see, thanks you for the pointers. So it would seem to be using a `styled-components` approach for the stuff we've done already, it was just the best approach to take around RN stylesheet.flatten, as it's the first time we've come across it in the codebase.

Looks like we have a bit of work ahead of us...

Comment: @Takuhii unfortunately, yes

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer is that no, there is no equivalent. I investigated and felt that `lodash.flatten` could work as a substitute, with a little tweaking, but in my case we converted the stylesheets to an object, and just removed the dependency on `stylesheet.flatten`